# Robocopy Invalid Parameter #7 Log

Tags: robocopy

I've been cracking my head trying to fix this. But it seems this command line isn't working for my `robocopy` batch file. It has something to do with the parameters, quotation marks, backslashes or maybe I'm just blind. I'm not too sure. Here's the code.

```
REM @Echo Off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
Set hostname=%COMPUTERNAME%

set torun=wmic bios get serialnumber /format:value
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('%torun%') do set serial=%%a

Set src="D:\BackUPTEST\%serial%"
set dest="D:\RestoreTEST\%serial%"
set logdest="D:\RestoreTEST\%serial%\Logs"

set logfile=Restore-%serial%.log
set log="%logdest%\%logfile%"

robocopy %src% %dest% /E /R:3 /W:3 /TEE /log:%log% /NP

echo Restore Completed. . .
ENDLOCAL
Echo On
```

I'm returned with...

> ERROR : Invalid Parameter #7 :
>   "/log:D:\RestoreTEST\CNU1293K2J\Logs\Restore-CNU1293K2J.log"
>
> ```
>    Simple Usage :: ROBOCOPY source destination /MIR
>
>          source :: Source Directory (drive:\path or \\server\share\path).
>     destination :: Destination Dir  (drive:\path or \\server\share\path).
>            /MIR :: Mirror a complete directory tree.
>
> For more usage information run ROBOCOPY /?
> ```
>
> ****  /MIR can DELETE files as well as copy them !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, figured out. As for Logging, there should be an existing Folder. So I simply added mkdir %logdest% before the robocopy command initializes... That seems to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Just been hit by the dreaded "Invalid log parameter"! 
Been using it for a year or more without problem, running on a network drive, then Robocopy V10 hit my machine a few days ago and it stopped working with the following message:

'\\SEAGATE-435DC3\usb1-1share1\BACKUP'

CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.

C:\Windows>robocopy X:\Documents Y:\BACKUP\Documents /s /XO /FFT /DST /TEE /NP /R:2 /W:5 /LOG:robocopy_docs.log

2016/11/10 19:07:47 ERROR 5 (0x00000005) Opening Log File C:\Windows\robocopy_docs.log
Access is denied.

So you now need to specify the path to the log file, then it works!
(Y: is mapped to \SEAGATE-435DC3\usb1-1share1)

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed the + out:   /LOG+:%logfile%